# Get pixel in a certain location

Tags: c#

I have a moving picturebox that moves with specified coordinates within a timer. However when the picturebox hits a certain picturebox I want it to stop.

I tried using a detect pixel setup, where if the pixel has changed then it will stop but however I cannot get it to work.

In other words, lets say I project this picturebox and it moves until its location it hits the target, but however the target is of many different colors and have different shapes.

Below I have a code that I tried using.

```
Bitmap myBit = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

for (int i = 1; i < myBit.Width; i++)
{
    for (int z = 1; z < myBit.Height; z++)
    {
        Color PixelColor = myBit.GetPixel(i, z);
        if (PixelColor.ToArgb() != Color.White.ToArgb())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Success");
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you check with the control positions itself instead of colors

Comment: if u mean location / coordinates. The target is weirdly shape similar to the shape of a tree and i dont want to code it for every singe corner and all.

Comment: Moving a picturebox does not change the colors of the pixels.

Comment: Then when you say that you have **a** certain picture box, you mean that you have **many** picture boxes.

Comment: I have 1 picturebox that moves and the target is stationary. SImilar to a bow and arrow game, where the arrow is moving as in picturebox control and the target could be a bulls eye

Comment: Scan the image once. Get all pixels that you must stop. Then use the rectangle of the smaller picture box and check if any of the points are in the rectangle.

Comment: could u perhaps write down a code I could use? Sorry I'm kinda new to all this and that would help a lot!!